# pandas dataframe sum with groupby

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe that structurally looks like this:

```
[
    ['x', '1', '-7']
    ['x', '2', '-2']
    ['y', '3', '-1']
    ['y', '4', '-3']
]
```

I have to groupby the first column (with values `x` and `y`s) and find the sum for the second and third column for each `x` and `y` like this:

```
[
    ['x', 3, -9]
    ['y', 7, -4]
]
```

How can I do this using pandas?

Comment: Have you tried using `groupby` and `sum`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***setup***
I converted your string numbers to actual numbers

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['x', '1', '-7'],
        ['x', '2', '-2'],
        ['y', '3', '-1'],
        ['y', '4', '-3']
    ]
)

df[1] = pd.to_numeric(df[1])
df[2] = pd.to_numeric(df[2])
```

***solution***

```
df.groupby(0).sum()
```

[image]